# How to return either "on" or "off" for: chkconfig --list | grep httpd

Tags: linux, shell-script, runlevel, chkconfig

To ensure httpd is automatically started on reboot.
I simply run this command

```
chkconfig httpd on
```

what I am looking for is a way to be told if this
setting is

```
on or off
```

instead of this command

```
chkconfig --list | grep httpd
```

which returns this

```
httpd           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
```

I understand about the levels but really what I need is

```
 on or off
```

so I can insert it onto a script and visually see on or off daily rather than something complex as above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from man page:

```
 By  default,  the on and off options affect only runlevels 2, 3, 4, and
   5, while reset and resetpriorities affects all of the  runlevels.   The
   --level option may be used to specify which runlevels are affected.
```

so you can use `awk` to extract only those levels(2,3,4,5):

```
chkconfig --list | grep httpd | awk '{ print $4 }' | cut -d ':' -f 2
```

and do the same for other levels(3,4,5) by replacing  `$4` by (`$5`,`$6`,`$7`)

Answer (score 2):

chkconfig actually just places symlinks to the services init-scripts usually found in /etc/init.d. So instead of grepping und awk'ing the output of chkconfig you can just check the existence of the symlink.

When I do a `chkconfig httpd on`, it creates a link called `/etc/rc3.d/S85httpd`, pointing to init.d. `chkconfig httpd off` removes that link (and does more, but that's rather irrelevant here). That might dependent of the distribution.

So in bash you can do `[ -f /etc/rc3.d/S85httpd ]`, and if the return value ( `$?`) is 0, the link exists. If it's 1, it does not, hence it's off.

Answer (score 1):

The given answers embed the runlevel in the script, while the question appears to ask for a single "on" or "off", implying it is for the current [runlevel](http://linux.die.net/man/8/runlevel).

Also it appears that the fact that [`chkconfig`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/chkconfig) accepts an argument was overlooked, making a `grep` redundant.

Also, its format is consistent, always putting the runlevel before the on/off items in its listing.  It is not necessary to count columns (and embed that in the work one must do to use the solution).

Taking those into account, here is a script which prints "on" or "off" for each given service at the current runlevel:

```
#!/bin/sh
THIS=$(runlevel | sed -e 's/^. //')
for svc in "$@"
do
  chkconfig --list $svc 2>/dev/null | sed -e 's/^.*'$THIS'://' -e 's/[[:space:]].*//'
done
```